# How can I disable pylint's missing-module-docstring for unit tests?

Tags: python, pytest, pylint, pylintrc

I'm a big fan of pylint's built-in docstring checker. I'm very happy to require docstrings on all my classes, all my functions, and all my modules.

What I don't like, however, is that pylint also wants docstrings on all my test modules and all my `pytest` test functions. This leads to low-value docstrings like the following:

```py
"""Tests for foo.py"""

from foo import bar

def test_bar():
    """Tests for bar"""
    assert bar(1) == 2
```

I've been able to disable the function-level docstring requirement using `no-docstring-rgx` in my [`.pylintrc` file](https://www.codeac.io/documentation/pylint-configuration.html):

```
[MASTER]
no-docstring-rgx=^(_|test_)
```

This takes care of the [`missing-function-docstring`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/convention/missing-function-docstring.html) / `C0116` error.

But I haven't been able to find a way to disable the [`missing-module-docstring`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/convention/missing-module-docstring.html) / `C0114` error just for files ending with `_test.py`. Is this possible with pylint?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer, can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

This sound like a new feature, I don't think an issue is opened for it. You can do so [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Needs+triage+%3Ainbox_tray%3A&template=FEATURE-REQUEST.yml)

Comment: Filed https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/8106